# Visual Studio deploy settings location for azure functions app

Tags: visual-studio, azure-functions

Where does Visual Studio save the remote app settings for an Azure Functions app when deploying? I don't see them in any of the project or solution files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**

Visual studio does not save the remote app settings locally, it always needs to read from azure function app.

You can test this by anyone of the following methods:

**Method 1**.Disconnect the network, then open visual studio -> the function app -> Publish -> Manage Application Settings: you can not see any settings there.

**Method 2**.With network connected, open Fiddler, then open visual studio -> the function app -> Publish -> Manage Application Settings, then check the http requests in fiddler, you can see there is a **post request**, and you can see all the remote settings are fetched via this request:

[image]

---

As per this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-develop-vs#function-app-settings), when click publish, you can see the remote app settings in the **Manage Application Settings** option, screenshot as below:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I would like to know where the settings are actually saved though. They must be in a file somewhere.

Comment: @VictorP, no, it does not save the remote app settings locally. Please refer to my updated answer.

Comment: @VictorP, if the issue is helpful, could you please help mark it as answer? thanks.